# MATLAB: Delete line hotkey?

Tags: matlab, keyboard

My trackpad is not comfortable to use so I aim to do coding with my keyboard only. 
My "kill line" hotkey do not work no matter what key I set it to. I did unassign all conflicts.

Simple question: 
Is there a way to make a hotkey, that will delete the line of code, the cursor (caret) is currently located on (not only all code after the cursor, like kill-line is supposed to do)?

Answer (score 6):

The `Kill line` (`Ctrl+K` by default in Windows) is working only in the Matlab console window by default. If you go to `File->Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts`, and select the `Kill Line` action line, in the next table (labeled `Shortcuts for Kill Line`) you will see two columns `Shortcut` and `Tolls with shortcut`. So you should make the `Tools with shortcut` to be `All tools` instead of `Command Window` by clicking on it and selecting everything.

Comment: This doesn't really work as requested though, as Kill line only deletes the part of text after the cursor.
There's no command in Matlab (R2016b) to delete a line, AFAIK.
(Please let me know if someone finds a workaround, using a plugin or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use AHK directly:

```
#IfWinActive,ahk_exe MATLAB.exe
    ^d::send,{End}{Home 2}+{Down}{Del}
#IfWinActive
```

You can change ^d (ctrl+d) to any other key you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is. You need to **create new shortcut**, pin it to quick access toolbar and run it with `Alt + number`  (or custom shortcut with AHK)

`Home` -> `New` -> `Command Shortcut`

Paste there this piece of code and fill `Label` field with i.e "Delete row" string and check `Add to quick access toolbar`.

```
currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
originalSelection =currentEditor.Selection;
row = originalSelection(1);% get row of cursor
C = strsplit(currentEditor.Text,'\n');% Split text of editor by lines
C(row) = [];%remove current row
currentEditor.Text = strjoin(C,'\n');%join it together
currentEditor.Selection =  [originalSelection(1) 1  originalSelection(1) 1 ];
  % make sure cursor is on the same line and on first position
```

[image: Shortcut editor]

Now your shortcut probably appear next to `Search documentation` text box.
Pressing `Alt + 1` will trigger the code and delete the row in editor.

Now you can change it to your custom shortcut keys with help of [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

```
#IfWinActive MATLAB    ;in MATLAB window
F11::                  ;pressing F11...
Send !1                ;triggers Alt + 1
```

**Edit**: After hour of testing I have to say, that this is working, but sadly not well, especially with larger scripts. There is delay and editor "blinks"...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Alamakanambra's solution is that it will unify multiple '\n' into a single '\n'

For example if this is your code:

```
y=eye(5)
x=eye(5)


% set m
m = length(x)

% display value of m
fprintf('value of m is: %d', m)
```

And you would like to remove this line: y=eye(5)
Then running the previous solution will output the following code:

```
x=eye(5)
% set m
m = length(x)
% display value of m
fprintf('value of m is: %d', m)
```

The desired output is:

```
x=eye(5)


% set m
m = length(x)

% display value of m
fprintf('value of m is: %d', m)
```

The solution is to use the CollapseDelimiters property, and set it to false in the strsplit method

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/zorik9/matlab-utils/tree/master/shortcuts)

This is the full solution:

```
currentEditor = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
originalSelection =currentEditor.Selection;
row = originalSelection(1)-1;% get row of cursor
C = strsplit(currentEditor.Text,'\n','CollapseDelimiters',false) % Split text of editor by lines
C(row) = [];%remove current row
currentEditor.Text = strjoin(C,'\n');%join it together
currentEditor.Selection =  [originalSelection(1)-1 1  originalSelection(1) 0 ];
  % make sure cursor is on the same line and on first position
```